# Connect multiple InkCanvas into one big InkCanvas

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

UWP has an InkCanvas. I'm trying to create an application that has multiple InkCanvas in a GridView which should appear to the user as one single InkCanvas. The problem right now is that if someone draws something in InkCanvas 1 it stops at the boundary of the canvas. The user has to release/stop pressing and then press again in the next InkCanvas.

Is there any way to draw across multiple InkCanvases without releasing the pen?

Comment: Handle when pen's coordinates are out of the canvas and automatically release pen?

Comment: And then automatically press pen again when in the other InkCanvas?

Comment: Could you tell me why do you use the `GridView`? It seems we can use one `InkCanvas` to draw the ink stroke.